# VB.net code -- Shows 'System.NullReferenceException' Oledb

Tags: vb.net

> **Error** ***An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in cust_db.exe  Additional
>   information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. in
>   vb.net***

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1
    Private conn As OleDbConnection
    Private adpt As OleDbDataAdapter
    Private cmd As OleDbCommandBuilder
    Public myds As DataSet
    Private str As String

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim cnstr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\database.mdb"
        conn = New OleDbConnection(cnstr)
        conn.Open()

        myds = New DataSet("customer")

        str = "SELECT * FROM customer"

        adpt = New OleDbDataAdapter(str, conn)
        adpt.SelectCommand.CommandText = str

        cmd = New OleDbCommandBuilder(adpt)
        adpt.Fill(myds, "cust")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If myds.Tables("cust") Is Nothing Then
            Dim newRow As DataRow = myds.Tables("cust").NewRow

            '   Dim newR As DataRow = myds.Tables("cust").NewRow
            newRow("cust_id") = TextBox1.Text
            newRow("cust_name") = TextBox2.Text
            newRow("cust_address") = TextBox3.Text
            newRow("cust_contactno") = TextBox4.Text

            myds.Tables("cust").Rows.Add(newRow)
            adpt.Update(myds, "cust")
            MessageBox.Show("Record successfully added!")
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: For future reference, it is good that you posted the error message and the relevant code, but that doesn't constitute a good question. You still need to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem, which includes a description of what you're trying to achieve and exactly where the issue arises.

Comment: What line is the exception thrown? What's the full stacktrace?

Comment: In your `Button1_Click` you check for the existence of a table called "cust", and only if that table does **not** exist, then you're using it.